# SignalR no transport

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Attempting to start signal-r hub reports "Error: No available transports found."

However, a diagnostic capture shows that negotiation returns *three* available transports.

```
{
    "connectionId": "IsHpe_1ETRLz-flnJ3uKPg",
    "availableTransports": [
        {
            "transport": "WebSockets",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text"
            ]
        },
        {
            "transport": "LongPolling",
            "transferFormats": [
                "Text",
                "Binary"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is done with aspnetcore 2.1 preview2 and startup looks like this

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAny", x =>
          x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin()));
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
        var connectionStrings = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
        var defaultConnectionString = connectionStrings[Configuration["DefaultConnectionString"]];
        services.AddDbContext<au1.Model.ProwlerDbContext>(options => 
          options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionString));
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowAny");
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

Obviously the route works, or negotiation wouldn't appear in the network traffic. Invoking http://local:5000/message with a browser produces a message `Connection ID required` as expected.

Have I left a step out?

On the client side, here's how I've tried to connect.

```
    this.signalr = new SignalR.HubConnection("http://localhost:5000/message");
    this.signalr.on("stateChange", (data: string) => {
        console.log(`SignalR: ${data}`);
        that.selection = data;
    });
    this.signalr.start().then(result=>{
        console.log("hub started");
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log("hub failed to start");
    });
```

package.json says `"_id": "@aspnet/signalr@1.0.0-preview1-update1",`

The .csproj says  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview2-final" />`

These are not the same. Whether they are compatible I could not say.

I don't know how these got out of synch as I omitted version to get the latest of each. An npm update brought the client to preview2 and I shall now retest.

Comment: Are your client and server versions in sync?

Comment: @Pawel - I don't know, I'm new to this. How would one check?

Comment: Go to the csproj file to check the server version (e.g. preview1), go to package.json to check the version of the client (if you used npm to install it). Make sure they are both `preview-X` (assuming you are using released bits)

Comment: @Pawel I have checked and amended the question with details.

Comment: @Pawel you were right!. Write that up as an answer, something along the lines of "As mentioned in the Packages section of the documentation, it is vitally important to ensure that your client and server library versions remain in lock step [details of how to check]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The versions of the server and the client have to align. You need to make sure that both client versions are the same by going to your .csproj file (for the version of the server and/or the version of the C# client) and to package.json for the version of the JavaScript/TypeScript client if you installed it using npm.

Note that there are breaking changes between previews so you cannot use a `-previewX` client with a `previewY` server.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'd made the same mistake and ended up with the error mentioned in question. Your answer quickly fixed the issue.

Comment: availableTransports getting null from android client what would be the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not had a chance to use the Java client so don't really know what can be happening. You can try opening an issue in the github repo.