# SignalR .NET Core 2.1 not working on proxied docker container

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, signalr, identityserver4, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .NET Core 2.1 Web API (using `2.1.0-preview1-final`) working fine locally using SignalR `1.0.0-preview1-final`. I'm using for the front-end an Angular app which has the package `"@aspnet/signalr": "1.0.0-preview1-final"` so everything matches and I have both HTTP endpoints and Hubs working as expected when I run the programs locally.

When I deploy to my virtual server I have an Nginx reverse proxy that sends request to all the applications behind it. I'm using Docker and I haven't had any problems with it in other projects when we deploy the v1.0 of an entire ecosystem.

The differences I have in this particular scenario are two:

1. I have IdentityServer4 using AspNetIdentity and had to remove the `proxy_buffering off` option from the Nginx configuration to get it to work (following https://andrewlock.net/fixing-nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-error-when-running-an-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes/)
2. I was reading that you shouldn't do 1) when using SignalR because you may have problems with it - not sure if this is the case now.

I'm capturing the logs of the API and I can see that when I try to connect to the Hubs I get back:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 7.4652ms 200 application/json
```

So I'm assuming this is correct. Now on the client side (Angular app): I see this:

> Error: Failed to start the connection. Error: No available transports found.

but if I inspect the response:

```
{"connectionId":"nHzKKYtp0ITwlEntjqLprA","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
```

**UPDATE**

Compared the response when running locally I got:

```
{"connectionId":"4ea7b1ea-8754-472b-baef-527073872d2a","availableTransports":["WebSockets","ServerSentEvents","LongPolling"]}
```

That means there is no restrictions in terms of transfer formats? Not sure if that's relevant either...It's very weird, it's the same thing that happens here: [SignalR no transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765667/signalr-no-transport)

------UPDATE END--------

So my questions are:

Have I broken SignalR connectivity because I did set the `proxy_buffer`? If so, is there a way to get both IS4 and SignalR running behind the same Nginx instance? - To make things more difficult I'm using an Nginx template that gets autogenerated using docker-gen.

If my changes to Nginx shouldn't break SignalR, why is not establishing the connection?

Thanks!

**UPDATE! FOUND THE ISSUE!!!**

I write this because I think that can be useful for someone else.

The problem I had was that I was using preview1 on both the client and the API but back in the day when I created the `Dockerfile` I couldn't get the `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.0-preview1-aspnetcore-runtime` to work so I chose to use `preview2`: `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.0-preview2-aspnetcore-runtime` and that was the problem. Now I quickly changed the client and the API to use preview of SignalR and I could get the connection to work. Happy days! Hope this el helpful :) So not only client and API need matching but the actual docker image needs to be aligned as well.

Comment: Is your signalr webapi hosted inside docker on https? If not try hosting it on https and see if that fix the issue

Comment: It is hosted on a Docker container which is proxied by Nginx (another Docker container) through HTTPS

Comment: So basically user needs to be authorised in order to be connected to hub(Authorize attribute applied at class level)? Have tried removing authorisation from hub to check if connection is successful in that case?

Comment: The token gets validated and I’m already logged in. When the page starts to load then the SignalR connection kicks in and that’s when the app fails

Comment: Right! I was just thinking of making sure that connection to hub will be successful if no identity server is involved so issue can be narrowed down to identity server or signalr

Comment: The only thing I can think of the Connection Upgrade header not been set explicitly in the nginx conf

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas Post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I had was that I was using preview1 on both the client and the API but back in the day when I created the Dockerfile I couldn't use the `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.0-preview1-aspnetcore-runtime` because I had metadata issues (taken from the error) so I chose to use preview2: `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.0-preview2-aspnetcore-runtime` and that was the problem. Now I quickly changed the client and the API to use preview of `SignalR` and I could get the connection to work. Happy days! Hope this el helpful :) So not only client and API need matching but the actual docker image needs to be aligned as well.

So make sure you have in sync you client version , net Core signalr versión and the runtime version of your `Dockerfile` when creating the image